# Undefined TypeScript enum at compile time

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have an enum defined in `types.ts`:

```js
export enum Handedness {
  Left,
  Right,
  Both,
}

export type State = {
  count: number
  handedness: Handedness
}
```

and I have an object being initialized in `state.ts`:

```js
import { State, Handedness } from './types'

export const initial: State = {
  count: 0,
  handedness: Handedness.Both
}
```

When I run tests (via `jest`) for this project, `state.ts` generates an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Both' of undefined`, telling me that `Handedness` isn't defined at the time it's referenced. But I'm exporting it from its module and importing it before I use it... so it should be defined.

I've found other similar questions asking about undefined enums, but they seem to all be asking about runtime. This is a compile time problem as far as I can tell.

I don't see what I would be doing wrong here. I import other types in other places without issue. But this enum simply doesn't want to work. What is going on here and how can I work around it?

Comment: I guess this is a typo in the question, but you have the property `okay` in your `State` type and then refer to it as `handedness` in your instance `initial`.

Answer (score 16):

Well, this isn't a way to get this to work, but [this GitHub PR](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/pull/308/files) explains that `ts-jest` won't support enums that work like this. I've changed all uses to (e.g.) `("both" as Handedness)` and it works. So, that's not an explanation, it's a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered similar error while running my code with Jest.
The issue was caused by a React component that imported an enum type from a module which was also being mocked with jest.mock.
I fixed the issue by using jest.spyOn for method that I needed instead of whole module.

from:
`jest.mock("example/path", () => ({ useExampleMethod: () => {...`

to:
`import * as exampleModule from "example/path"; jest.spyOn(exampleModule , 'useExampleMethod').mockReturnValue({...`

Answer (score 6):

Similar issue here, but a slightly different cause & solution. Posting here in hopes that this helps others.

1. I was defining my enum in a file `/auth/types.ts`:

```js
....
export enum SampleEnum {
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND = 2
}
```

2. I was then exporting my types en-masse from `/auth/index.ts`:

```js
export * from './types;
```

3. Finally, I was importing this from the parent directory elsewhere in the app:

```js
import { SampleEnum } from './auth'
...

const someOtherObject = {
  place: SampleEnum.FIRST
}
```

Running Jest, I was getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIRST' of undefined` error, even when the code compiled just fine.

To solve this, I switched my import statement to

```js
import { SampleEnum } from './auth/types'
```

Comment: This solution works for me too, but it really isn't the solution I'm looking for, as the IDE always suggests the problematic path. I'm looking for a more systematic solution :-(

Comment: This is the reason why I've strongly started supporting using string literals over enums. Not because I think string literals are better (or enums are better) but because I seem to run into circular import issues sometimes when using enums whereas I will never run into them using literals.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try using [const enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums).

So change:

```
export enum Whatever { ... }
```

to

```
export const enum Whatever { ... }
```

[Apparently](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/281#issuecomment-500780488) as of `ts-jest` version 23.10 you can just do this. Much better!

Comment: This is the solution for making it work for ts-jest. I am completely sure why this works though. It would be good to know about it.

Comment: That doesn't work with Vitest it seems. Or it just doesn't work for me, for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` does not work over enums. use `for` instead:

```
for (const cor in Payment_Corresponding_Invoice_Status) {
      if (cor[0] === statusEnumKey) {
        correspondingInvoiceValue = cor[1];
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: replace Payment_Corresponding_Invoice_Status with your enum name